Ovalness of a polygon measure or a classifier
I'm looking for a computationally not very expensive algorithm or a library function to measure ovalness of a polygon or a binary classifier: an oval or not an oval. Here are a few examples of oval polygons in my arbitrary and subjective classification:

And examples of not ovals:


Don't mind slightly different scales, only the shape is relevant.

What do you mean by "ovalness"? Which has more ovalness, a pentagon or a semicircle? And why? There's plenty of heuristics one might imagine, but without a clearer idea of the precise property being estimated there would be no way to objectively evaluate their effectiveness.

@Sneftel Unfortunately, I don't have a precise definition. In your example, a pentagon has much more ovalness than a semicircle due to better central symmetry. Propose something that works on the examples I provided. I'm using criteria based on oriented_envelope from Python shapely library (https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/shapely.oriented_envelope.html), e.g. aspect ratio < 2 and ratios of length and areas of the polygon to its oriented envelope.

Well, in your examples, the not-ovals both have acute sharp angles, and none of the ovals do. So just measure the maximum curvature at any given point in the polygon, and call it an oval if that’s under some threshold.

@Sneftel It will not work. Even after simplification, there are acute angles in "ovals", e.g. upper right example.

Not as acute. That’s where the threshold comes in. The maximum curvature in those is significantly less than in the non-ovals.

@PaulJurczak, are you still working on this problem? Found a solution? If not I could work through a few ideas.

@Rethunk I will be returning to this problem this weekend. I will post my ad hoc solution.

@Rethunk I will be using pattern matching, i.e. similarity measure between approximation of the polygon in question and a template generated from its oriented_envelope.

@PaulJurczak, I was thinking of oriented rectangle for the start as well, but then check for symmetry, and then try a (hopefully) efficient iterative technique to check for closeness to different eggy shapes. Calculation of moments could be useful. If the initial rectangle fit is assumed useful, then I can imagine processing the closed curve by quadrants within the rectangle. Would you be able to provide a bit more context about the application? Are these edge results from segmentation  of some natural shapes?

@Rethunk I posted my solution. Not looking for symmetry violations yet. They are most likely not needed for my use case. Can't disclose the specifics.

Here is my ad-hoc solution using the sum of squares of distances to an octagonal pattern build on oriented_envelope after some normalization.
import numpy as np
from shapely import *
from itertools import pairwise
from shapely.affinity import scale


def getRadius(rect):
  return LineString(rect.boundary.coords[:3]).length/2


def getAspectRatio(rect):
  d0 = LineString(rect.boundary.coords[0:2]).length
  d1 = LineString(rect.boundary.coords[1:3]).length
  
  return min(d0, d1)/max(d0, d1)


def getOctagon(rect):
  v0 = np.array(rect.boundary.coords)
  v1 = []

  for u, v in pairwise(v0):
    v1.append(u + 0.33*(v-u))
    v1.append(u + 0.66*(v-u))

  return LinearRing(v1)


def getOvalness(contour, nVerticesTarget=32, maxPixelLen=250, minAspectRatio=0.4, maxLenRatio=0.9, cScale=10):
  if not(nVerticesTarget <= len(contour) <= maxPixelLen):
    return None

  decimated = contour[::round(len(contour)/nVerticesTarget), ::-1]
  poly = Polygon(decimated)
  env = poly.oriented_envelope

  if not(minAspectRatio <= getAspectRatio(env) and poly.length/env.length <= maxLenRatio):
    return None
  
  r = getRadius(env)
  target = scale(poly, cScale/r, cScale/r)
  env = target.oriented_envelope
  pattern = getOctagon(env)
  ovalness = 0

  for p in target.exterior.coords:
    ovalness += distance(Point(p), pattern)**2

  return nVerticesTarget/len(decimated)*ovalness

And the results on polygonal circle, ellipse and a few real world contours created with skimage.measure.find_contours() applied to a video frame.


The original answer was edited to correct point to geometry distance calculation. The results look even better.

Nice! The numbers suggest a clear distinction between what intuitively looks like an oval, and what wouldn't be considered an oval. The distance-to-polygon calculation feels right to me, especially given the efficiency of that calculation for an octagon. Although there are some algorithmic alternatives I (or you) might explore, if the day had 36 hours instead of 24, your solution strikes a good balance. Bravo!

You can solve the system of equations to find the ellipse shape (minor/major axis lengths) from the given perimeter and area values using sympy:
import sympy as sp


def ellipse_perimeter(w, h):
    a, b = w/2, h/2
    return (3*(a+b) - sp.sqrt((3*a+b)*(a+3*b)))*sp.pi

def ellipse_area(w, h):
    a, b = w/2, h/2
    return sp.pi*a*b

# w = minor axis length
# h = major axis length
w, h, perimeter, area = sp.symbols('w h perimeter area')

# expressions
perimeter_expr = ellipse_perimeter(w, h)
area_expr = ellipse_area(w, h)

# equations
perimeter_eq = sp.Eq(perimeter_expr, perimeter)
area_eq = sp.Eq(area_expr, area)

# need find `width` and `height` of ellipse 
# from system of known equations
solutions = sp.solve((area_eq, perimeter_eq), (w, h))

Then, iterate through the solutions to find the corresponding formulas for expressing the width and height of the ellipse:
w, h = 20, 60

params = dict(perimeter=ellipse_perimeter(w, h), area=ellipse_area(w, h))
eval_expr = lambda expr: sp.re(expr.subs(params).evalf())
for i, (w_formula, h_formula) in enumerate(solutions):
    print(f"solution {i+1}:")
    
    # show as mathjax in jupyter
    # display(w_formula)
    # display(h_formula)

    print(w_formula)
    print(h_formula)

    print(f"  w = {eval_expr(w_formula)}")
    print(f"  h = {eval_expr(h_formula)}")
    print()

You don't need to run all the code above. Here's the ready-to-use code with the ellipse_shape function from the solution:
from math import sqrt, pi

def ellipse_perimeter(w, h):
    a, b = w/2, h/2
    return (3*(a+b) - sqrt((3*a+b)*(a+3*b)))*pi

def ellipse_area(w, h):
    a, b = w/2, h/2
    return pi*a*b

def ellipse_shape(area, perimeter):
    term1 = sqrt(3)*sqrt(8*pi*area + perimeter**2)
    term2 = sqrt((3*perimeter + term1)**2 - 144*pi*area)
    term3 = (3*perimeter + term1 - term2)

    w = term3/(6*pi)
    h = 24*area/term3
    return (w, h)


# We know the exact ellipse shape
# First, we calculate the area and perimeter from the shape
# Next, we'll deduce the shape using its calculated area and perimeter
w, h = 20, 60
w, h = min(w, h), max(w, h)

# Calculate ellipse characteristics from known shape
area = ellipse_area(w, h)
perimeter = ellipse_perimeter(w, h)

# Reconstructing ellipse shape (w', h') from area and perimeter
w_est, h_est = ellipse_shape(area, perimeter)

# Helper function to check if two values are close
is_close = lambda l, r: abs(l-r) < 1e-4

# Verify that derived shape matches original
assert is_close(w, w_est)
assert is_close(h, h_est)


You can solve the system of equations to find the ellipse shape. I fail to see how your answer is relevant to my question.

@PaulJurczak Calculating shape factor using perimeter and area of your figures could be beneficial. I had this code already and decided to format it for those seeking something similar, leaving it here as a potentially useful resource.
